# How to fix an image in a modal header with bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to insert a simple logo in my header of modal. 
But i'm using bootstrap-vue and I haven't really a header, then I don't know how to insert an image. I'm trying with the parameters img="", the css with the id but that's not working.

[In top of modal like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnof6.jpg)

```
    <b-modal
       id="modal-1"
       ref="authenticate-modal"
       hide-footer
       v-model="modalOpen"
    >
      <b-tabs class="px-3 pb-3">
        <b-tab title="Se connecter" active>
           <Login />
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="S'inscrire">
           <Register />
        </b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom html in modal-title slot as below.

Read the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods) for more details

```
 <b-modal
       id="modal-1"
       ref="authenticate-modal"
       hide-footer
       v-model="modalOpen"
    >
  <div slot="modal-title">
    Authenticate Modal
    <img :src="imgpath"></img>
  </div>
</b-modal>
```